# Can a Java interface be defined such that only Enums can extend it?

Tags: java, enums

There's no particular reason I want to do this - I'm just wondering if it is possible. If it helps, here's a fictional situation in which it could be used:

Imagine a type of `Enum` which is used as a read-only data source, such that each value of the `Enum` contains distinct content. The `Enum` implements `Readable`. Now, suppose we want a method that reads all values of the `Enum` into a single buffer. That could be implemented as a static utility method in a helper class (see below).

```
public class ReadableEnumUtils {
    /** reads data from all enum values into the charbuffer */
    public static <T extends Enum<T> & Readable> int readAll(Class<T> clazz, CharBuffer cb) throws IOException {
        int total = 0;
        for (T e : clazz.getEnumConstants()) {
            int intermediate = e.read(cb);
            if (intermediate < 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The enum value \'" + e.name() + "\' had no data to read.");
            }
            total += intermediate;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Preferably, that method would be declared in an interface, but that could be confusing, since it wouldn't be immediately obvious that non-Enum classes should not implement such a method. Ideally, the interface could be defined in such a way that the compiler would ensure it was only implemented by subclasses of `Enum`. Here's an example of what that interface could possibly look like:

```
interface ReadableEnum extends Readable {
    int read(CharBuffer cb) throws IOException;

    int readAll(CharBuffer cb) throws IOException;
}
```

I don't think it's possible to make the compiler ensure that `ReadableEnum` is only implemented by subclasses of `Enum` - is that correct?

Comment: i dont think its possible

Comment: *There's no particular reason to do this* even if it is only to satisfy your curiosity, you still need to show some effort to have come up with a solution. [mcve] is not only for questions that have a particular reason behind them.

Comment: Why would you wonder about this if you don't have a specific application that requires it?  Can you show how this could be used and what the advantage would be?

Comment: @jrook There is no need for a reproducible example, as this Question is not asking about problematic code. This Question is asking about the Java language and its capabilities/limitations with respect to the Java enum facility. There is no code to be fixed here. Some folks have forgotten the original mission of Stack Overflow, to be a knowledge base. Granted a bit more explanation of how this issue arose would help to focus a response, but this Question is legitimate as written.

Comment: @BasilBourque I didn't vote to close the question nor did I say it was not a legitimate question. I just downvoted it and explained why. IMHO, "is it possible *some random thought about a programming language*" is best answered by Google not SO, at least at first.

Comment: @jrook The founders stated that one of their main goals in creating Stack Overflow was for a quality on-point page at S.O. would appear in just such a Google search.

Comment: @BasilBourque Ok, and I agree that maybe my comment is not the best way to improve the question. But I still think the tooltip on downvote button applies here. Others may disagree in which case they have the option of upvoting or answering. As I said, I am not raising a flag.

Comment: @jrook Fair enough. My comment was not really aimed at you in particular. I'm just bothered by what I find to be troubling trends growing on Stack Overflow: (a) voting down legitimate Questions with demands to "just Google it", and (b) demanding reproducible code samples *everywhere*. There *are* some Questions where demanding code samples is appropriate, but not routinely on all. And actually, Stack Overflow currently has much more troubling trends than these two.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can actually do something like that using few tricks, I will try to write an answer in few hours.

Comment: Yep, it's possible with annotation processors, that are part of java, so we could say that it is possible in java. Definitely will do the job of throwing compiler error if someone will try to use this interface in wrong place

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Java by default does not support anything like that, you ask why not with link to specification, but there is no special reason why, just no one decided to add such feature, you could propose it yourself - but then you will probably learn that they don't think it's something needed and will not add this to the language.

But java provides pretty powerful option to implement this by yourself: annotation processing.
I've created simple java 8 maven project with annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface EnumInterface {}
```

And with special processor

```
import javax.annotation.processing.*;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.*;
import javax.lang.model.type.*;
import javax.lang.model.util.Types;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;
import java.util.*;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.gotofinal.enuminterface.EnumInterface")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
public class EnumInterfaceProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        Messager messager = processingEnv.getMessager();
        Types typeUtils = processingEnv.getTypeUtils();

        // first we scan for all interfaces marked with this annotation
        List<TypeElement> enumOnlyInterfaces = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Element rootElement : roundEnv.getRootElements()) { // getRootElements should return all types being compiled
            if (! (rootElement instanceof TypeElement)) {
                continue;
            }
            TypeMirror typeMirror = rootElement.asType();
            // we check if this class have our annotation, we could also here check if this is an interface (by checking if it does not extend Object directly) and throw error otherwise
            if (rootElement.getAnnotation(EnumInterface.class) != null) {
                enumOnlyInterfaces.add((TypeElement) rootElement);
            }
        }

        // and now we scan for any non enum types that implement this interface
        for (Element rootElement : roundEnv.getRootElements()) {
            if (! (rootElement instanceof TypeElement)) {
                continue;
            }
            TypeElement type = findImplementedInterface(rootElement.asType(), enumOnlyInterfaces, typeUtils);
            if (type == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (! (rootElement.asType() instanceof DeclaredType)) {
                continue;
            }

            // it's fine if it is an enum
            if (this.isEnum(rootElement.asType(), typeUtils)) {
                continue;
            }

            // and we print error to compiler
            messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, "Interface " + type.getQualifiedName()
                                                                 + " can't be used on non enum class: " + ((TypeElement) rootElement).getQualifiedName());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public TypeElement findImplementedInterface(TypeMirror type, List<TypeElement> interfaces, Types types) {
        for (TypeElement anInterface : interfaces) {
            // types.isSubtype(typeA, typeA) would return true, so we need to add this equals check
            if (!anInterface.asType().equals(type) && types.isSubtype(type, anInterface.asType())) {
                return anInterface;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // maybe there is better way to do this... but I just scan recursively for a subtype with java.lang.Enum name, so it's not perfect but should be enough.
    public boolean isEnum(TypeMirror type, Types types) {
        for (TypeMirror directSupertype : types.directSupertypes(type)) {
            TypeElement element = (TypeElement) ((DeclaredType) directSupertype).asElement();
            if (element.getQualifiedName().contentEquals("java.lang.Enum")) {
                return true;
            }
            if (isEnum(directSupertype, types)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And register it in `META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor` file:

```
com.gotofinal.enuminterface.EnumInterfaceProcessor
```

This code could be probably improved a lot, I've never wrote any annotation processor before. But when we will create another maven project and declare this one as dependency and write code like this:

```
@EnumInterface
interface TestInterface {}

enum TestEnum implements TestInterface {}

class TestClass implements TestInterface {}
```

We will not be able to compile it with error:

> Interface com.gotofinal.enuminterface.TestInterface can't be used on non enum class: com.gotofinal.enuminterface.TestClass

Answer (score 6):

If all implementations of an interface extend a certain class, then all instances of the interface are instances of the class as well; therefore, this interface must also extend this class ([read more about *is-a relationship* and subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming))).

Since [*each type in the extends clause of an interface declaration must be an **interface** type*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.3), you can't make your interface extend `Enum` **class**; therefore, you can't prevent not-enum classes from implementing your interface.

You can't even achieve it by replacing `interface ReadableEnum extends Enum` with `abstract class ReadableEnum extends Enum` since *[**enum** types **must not be** declared **abstract**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)*.

---

But you can still make it harder to implement `ReadableEnum` for not-enum classes by making it extend `IEnum` interface which consists of all public `Enum` methods:

```
public interface IEnum<E extends Enum<E>> extends Comparable<E> {
    String name();
    int ordinal();
    Class<E> getDeclaringClass();
}
```

```
interface ReadableEnum<E extends Enum<E> & ReadableEnum<E>> extends Readable, IEnum<E> {
    int read(CharBuffer cb) throws IOException;

    default int readAll(CharBuffer cb) throws IOException {
        return ReadableEnumUtils.readAll(getDeclaringClass(), cb);
    }
}
```

Now enums can implement `ReadableEnum` just by implementing `read` method, while other classes have to implement `name`, `ordinal`, `getDeclaringClass` and `compareTo` as well.