# How to implement a generic interface where type param is Enum and some other type

Tags: java, generics, enums, parameterization

I'm working with an interface that accepts a type parameter:

```
public interface Container<T>
```

Now I can have a class as such that implements it:

```
public class EnumContainer implements Container<Enum>
```

But now suppose I want a `Container` for enums that implements a interface called `Position`:

```
public interface Position {
   String getAbbreviation();
   String getDescription();
}
```

How can I define `PositionEnumContainer`? I've tried this but it's a compile time error:

```
public class PositionEnumContainer implements Container<Enum & Position>
```

I do not want to make `PositionEnumContainer` generic such as:

```
public class PositionEnumContainer <T extends Enum<T> & Position> implements Container<T>
```

Comment: Why did you put a generic in `Enum<T>`?

Comment: In the last code snippet, I put `Enum<T>` to indicate that T is an Enum of type T. Enum itself is generic.

Comment: ...`public class PositionEnumContainer implements Container<Enum>, Position`? Because your class implements the Container interface, and the Position interface? That's how interfaces work: you list every interface your class implements, separated by a comma.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans - Thanks for response. I do not want `PositionEnumContainer` to implement `Position`. Rather, I want the `Container` to hold objects that are both of type `Enum` and of type `Position`.

Comment: Then my counter-question is: why? Those are not unifiable, so just "wanting" that is not good enough: it needs to make sense. By all means, create a `class PositionedEnum implements Enum, Position` and then make something that implements `Container<PositionedEnum>`. Generics is about identifying _the one thing_ that you promise is going to get used, not "one of several completely incompatible things".

Answer (score 0):

You can make `PositionEnumContainer` implement `Container<Enum<? extends Position>>`.

If a class extends `Enum<? extends Position>` then it's an `enum class` that also implements `Position`, therefore, `PositionEnumContainer` will only accept objects that are both of type `Enum` and of type `Position`. But unfortunately, Java doesn't know about it, so `PositionEnumContainer`'s producing methods will return `Enum<? extends Position>`, that can't be implicitly cast back to `Position`, and you will have to cast it yourself or use safe `Enums#narrow` method.

```
public class Enums {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // only class E can extend Enum<E>
    public static <E extends Enum<E>> E narrow(Enum<E> obj) {
        return (E) obj;
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can create the `PositionEnum` interface that `extends Position` and [can only be implemented by enums](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58595689/10536125) and then make `PositionEnumContainer` implement `Container<PositionEnum>`. In this case, each `ConcretePositionEnum` will have to implement `PositionEnum<ConcretePositionEnum>` instead of `Position`.

```
// should only be implemented by enums
// you can verify it with annotation processor
public interface IEnum<E extends Enum<E>> extends Comparable<E> {
    String name();
    int ordinal();
    Class<E> getDeclaringClass();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    default E self() { return (E) this; }
}

public interface PositionEnum<E extends Enum<E> & Position> extends IEnum<E>, Position {}
```